# Is it possible to get an element's position in an array through MongoDB C# Query?

Tags: c#, mongodb

I store instances of a .NET class in a MongoDB collection via C# drivers. The class contains an array for example - MyArray. Is it possible to query a certain string(element)'s position in the array with the MongoDB C# driver? Practical example is I want to find the documents in the collection whose MyArray property has a certain string on the position 0.

Thanks a lot.

the .NET Class:

```
    namespace TestClasses
{
     public class TestClass
    {
        public TestClass() {

        }

        public string[] MyArray
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        protected string Name
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, by using the dot notation in your query (where searchValue is the value you are looking):

```
MongoServer server = MongoServer.Create(host);
MongoDatabase db = server.GetDatabase(databaseName);
MongoCollection Collection = db.GetCollection("collection");

var query = new QueryDocument("MyArray.0", searchValue);
var testCollection = matchCollection.FindAs<TestClass>(query);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Jeffsaracco.Now I have a more complicated case. Now I have another array in the class -  MyArray2. What I want to do is firstly to find the documents whose MyArray contains the given string String1 and then find the position of the given string in MyArray and filter out documents whose element on the same position of MyArray2 is the given string String2. Suppose MyArray and MyArray2 is string array and has no duplicate element. Is it possible?

Comment: I think the only way to do that is by doing some map/reduce function  in which you process the arrays using javascript or by doing a query like 
    {"MyArray1" : {$exists:true}, "MyArray2" : {$exists:true}}
then getting the documents back and processing them on the server side. I do no think MongoDB has any kind of operators for what you are looking for

Comment: Yes, I did exactly on this way. I get the documents back and process them on the server side. Thanks.